# If $A$ and $B$ are measurable sets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ with positive Lebesgue measure then $A-B$ contains an interval??

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Attempt to this problem: I tried in the way that firstly $A=B$ and the set is bounded then we know that the function $f(x)=m(A \cap (A+x))$ is a continuous map because $f$ is a convolution of $1_A$ and $1_{-A}$. And $f(0)>0$ so we can do it using neighborhood property.

Thinking in this way I thought that $f(x)=m(A \cap (B+x))$ is continuous, but what guarantee is there that there is an $x$ such that $m(A \cap (B+x))>0$, so we proceed like previously?

So how should I proceed? Any help is welcome. Thanks...

Comment: @kavi rama murthy

Comment: I am not him, but this answer should be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3819775/difference-of-lebesgue-measurable-sets

Basically to see your function is nonzero you should integrate it, and then use the fact that an integral of a convolution $\chi_A*\chi_{-B}$ is a product of the integrals of $\chi_A$ and $\chi_{-B}$ separately.

Comment: The argument in the link given by Glare works: Just replace intervals by disks.